# Installing Boson Netsim on Mac M1

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to get Boson Netsim to run on my new Mac OS M1.
I am unable to get Windows to run using Virtual Box. Just found that it is not yet supported on M1. I only get an option for Windows 32 bit on Virtual box  in Mac.
Is there any other way that I can run this on Mac M1?

Answer (score 2):

Windows won't run on an ARM-powered Mac.

Currently the only way to run Windows is using the unsupported [Windows for ARM](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-test-windows-10-arm-insider-on-m1-macs/7082dca1-f70c-4986-a73f-4770a11c86d4) beta & the M1 technical preview of [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/blogs/parallels-desktop-apple-silicon-mac/).